# calculating % difference for every row with the same ID

Tags: mysql, database-design, greatest-n-per-group

Right now I have a table that looks like this but with around 1 million rows and over 100 company names.

```
Date  |  Company  | Price
10/08/16  Exxon      2.00
10/08/16  Shell      1.95
11/08/16  Exxon      2.01
11/08/16  Shell      1.97
```

What is the best way to go about calculating the percent difference per day per company so that I end up with a table or view that looks like this.

```
Date  | Company | % difference
10/08/16  Exxon     .56
10/08/16  Shell     .24
11/08/16  Exxon     1.005
11/08/16  Shell     1.01
```

would it be better to store each company as a column or keep it in row format, also how would I write the function so its not recalculating all million rows every day when I import new information.

Comment: See if MariaDB's Windowing functions will make that easy to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote out an answer that works in SQL Server before noticing you have this question tagged as MySQL.  For context, if you weren't in MySQL you'd use the `LAG` function like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.P_date, 
    s.Company, 
    s.Price, 
    s.Price/s.Last_price as Percent_diff
FROM
(   SELECT 
        t.P_date, 
        t.Company, 
        t.Price,
        LAG(t.Price) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Company ORDER BY t.Company, t.P_Date)  Last_price
    FROM YourTable as t
) as s
```

The `LAG` line selects the `Price` value from the last record for the same company, allowing the outer query to do the percent calculation.

But MySQL doesn't support `LAG`.  Luckily there's an answer on Stack Overflow that shows how to simulate `LAG` in MySQL.  It even uses an example table almost identical to yours:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303532/simulate-lag-function-in-mysql

I suggest you do this as a view, not a table.  That way the calculation will only run when you select from the view, leaving you free to update your main table without worrying about those million rows bogging you down.